# TypeError: Incorrect type of self (must be 'StereoMatcher' or its derivative) in Opencv

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, stereoscopy

**Description:**
I am following the [sample code](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_calib3d/py_depthmap/py_depthmap.html) to find the disparity.

**Code:**

```
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
imgL = cv2.imread('tsukuba_l.png',0)
imgR = cv2.imread('tsukuba_r.png',0)
stereo = cv2.StereoBM(numDisparities=16, blockSize=15)
disparity = stereo.compute(imgL,imgR)
plt.imshow(disparity,'gray')
plt.show()
```

**But the error I got is:**

```
File "D:drawing-epipolar-lines/untitled0.py", line 15, in <module>
disparity = stereo.compute(imgL,imgR)
TypeError: Incorrect type of self (must be 'StereoMatcher' or its derivative)
```

Comment: Does this help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27726306/python-opencv-computing-a-depth-map-from-stereo-images